# How to manage features that depend on libraries that may or may not be installed?

Tags: c, dependencies, libraries

I'm writing some new functionality for a graphics program (written mostly in C, with small parts in C++). The new functionality will make use of libgmic. Some users of the program will have libgmic installed, quite a lot will not. The program is monolithic: I'm not writing a plugin, this will be part of the main program. Compiling the program with the right headers is easy, but I need to be able to check *at runtime* whether the library is installed on the user's system or not in order to enable / disable the particular menu item so that users without the library installed can't invoke this piece of functionality and crash the program. What's the best way of going about this?

Comment: Either supply the library with the code (like AppImage) or check in your installer whether it is present.

Comment: The usual way to do this is have your package detect during compilation if a library exists or not, and compile appropriately. Another option is to static compile your package.

Comment: @stark: How do you figure “check in your installer” satisfies the stated requirement to “check at runtime”?

Comment: Methods of doing what you ask depend on the target system, and you have not stated what the target system(s) are. [Some systems have services for opening libraries dynamically and testing whether a symbol (such as a function name) is available.](https://linux.die.net/man/3/dlsym) There may also be “weak linking” features that bind symbols into the executable if they are available but do not fail if they are not, and then the symbols would have zero/null values at run time.

Comment: @EricPostpischil  Runtime for the installer, of course!

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified the target platforms are *nix, Windows, MacOS. The program is FOSS and users can of course compile it for themselves, but most will obtain a prebuilt binary. The library that they may or may not have is distributed separately: I am not keen to include an additional copy of it with the software I'm contributing to, because that puts an onus on my software to keep up with changes to the lib, but rather to enable the feature if the library is installed and if it's not, print a message telling the user they need to install the library if they want to use the feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the library at runtime with `dlopen` (or `LoadLibrary` on Windows) instead of linking to it, get function pointers with `dlsym` (`GetProcAddress` on Windows) and use them instead of function prototypes from the headers. Otherwise your program will simply fail to startup without the library (or crash, in some cases).

Some libraries support such usage well, such as providing types for all the functions you need. With others you’re on your own but that’s still possible.